# Why nested ng-grid height does not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a nested ng grid.

```
var faculty = angular.module('faculty', ['ngGrid']);

faculty.controller('facultycontroller', function facultycontroller($scope, $http, $window)
{

$scope.facdata = [{

    examname: 'test'       
  },{

    examname: 'test2'
  }];

  $scope.gridOptions = {

    data: 'facdata',

    plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],

    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'examname',displayName: 'Exam Name'},
      {field: '', displayName: 'Subjects' , cellTemplate: '<div  ng-grid="gridOptions1"  ></div>'
    }]
  };
$scope.fac1data = [{
    abc: 'value',
    def: 'value2'
  }, {

    abc: 'value3',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value1',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value2',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {

    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value23',
    def: 'value14'
  }, {
    abc: 'value433',
    def: 'value5554'
  }, {

    abc: 'value3555',
    def: 'value4878'
  }
  ];
$scope.gridOptions1 = {

   plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],

    data: 'fac1data',

    columnDefs: [

      {  field: 'abc',displayName: 'abc'},

      { field: 'def',displayName: 'def'}]
  }
});
```

See the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ow4Q7lzz2hoDOENE3Jn7?p=preview)
I need to show all of the nested data grid at a glance. I need to show child ng-grid data at a glance(without Vertical scroll). But nested grid height does not work . My desire grid is like below....

[image: Mater Detail Grid/Nested Grid]

Comment: I see what you want to do, but it's simply not supported. It HAS been requested: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/883

Comment: The **suggested solution** is "setting the row height to be large enough" https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/343

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ng-grid was not designed for nested grids:** *Or even dynamic height cell by cell*

If you look ng-grid's template `ui-grid.html` you see that the size is fixed in pixels:

```
  height: {{ grid.options.rowHeight }}px;
```

### see  **[github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/ui-grid.html#L9)**

This ***CSS*** class is embedded in the template, leaving no room to over-write to "auto".  Since grids are built with `Div's` rather than `Tables`, tabular relationships between rows and columns is difficult if every `cell-div` is free to decide it's own behavior. So nested grids are quite the challenge.

---

You **CAN** get the affect you want with **a hack that resembles nested grids**:

### see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAHRHGhCjjS543Vfo5pg?p=preview)

**Collapsed Grid**
[image]

**note:** The caret's have been added to show that parent rows are expandable. I have'nt added logic to hide carets for parent rows that have no children.

**Expanded Grid**
[image]

### see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAHRHGhCjjS543Vfo5pg?p=preview)

---

**Alter your JSon** to include a column for Test, Name, andd Score. Use columns for either Test names or Student Names/Scores. use parent id for children and give id's to parents:

```
$scope.facdata  = [{test: "Basic Physics Test", parentId:0,id:1,expanded:true},
                 {name: "NAME", Score: "SCORE",parentId:1,expanded:false},
                 {name: "John", Score: 77,parentId:1,expanded:false},
                 {name: "Jacob", Score: 66,parentId:1,expanded:false},
                 {name: "Jenny", Score: 94,parentId:1,expanded:false},
                 {test: "Advanced Physics Test",id:2, parentId:0,expanded:true},
                 {name: "NAME", Score: "SCORE",parentId:2,expanded:false},
                 {name: "Freddy", Score: 94,parentId:2,expanded:false},
                 {name: "Samantha", Score: 38,parentId:2,expanded:false},
                 {name: "Judy", Score: 100,parentId:2,expanded:false}
                 ];
```

**In Grid Options** set `rowTemplate` to use `ng-show` directive on the children against the `expanded` field

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'facdata',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'id',displayName:'',width:20,
    cellTemplate:'<div ng-show="row.getProperty(\'id\')" ng-click="toggleExpansion(row.getProperty(col.field))"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>'},
                {field: 'test', displayName: ''},
                {field: 'name', displayName:''},
                 {field:'Score', displayName:'', 
                 cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>'}],
    rowTemplate:'<div style="width: 600px" ng-show="row.getProperty(\'expanded\')"><div ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" class="ngCell ">' +
                       '<div ng-cell></div> </div></div>'
```

Add a ToggleSubReport function to manage showing the embedded data

```
$scope.ToggleSubReport  = function(id) {
  for (var i=0;i<$scope.facdata.length;++i){
    if ($scope.facdata [i].parentId ===id){
      $scope.facdata [i].expanded = !$scope.facdata [i].expanded;
    }
  }
}
```

### see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAHRHGhCjjS543Vfo5pg?p=preview)

:

:

---

### **Followup for Amin Uddin (Original Poster)**

1) **Nested Grids are not possible:**
This was your main question and aim. This is what you put a bounty on. But as you can see from **[github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/ui-grid.html#L9)** sourcefor grid-row height (defined in pixels) and responses from ***ng-grid*** contributors, this is not an option yet they even envision. ***NG-Grid's*** cell height is not truly dynamic because ***ng-grid*** is designed around matching sized `divs` rows rather than a `table` (which can more naturally re-size rows and row-cells).

2) **A Sub-Grid of the kind I showed you really can accomodate sophisticated master-child relationships:** You can merge arrays before serializing them (or parse ***JSON*** strings to arrays, then merge them). You must redefine the fields I used for master-detail from the unimaginative `id/parentid` I used to the `PK/FK` of the 2 lists.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right for sub grid. But my object is more complex. So I need to implement master detail grid/nested grid concept. My object like this... public class Order { public string OrderNO(get; set;) public DateTime OrderDate(get; set;) public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetailList {get; set;} } public class OrderDetail { public string ProductName{get; set;} public decimal Price{get;set;} public int Quantity{get;set;} }

Comment: @AminUddin, the ONLY way to deal with that is to create JSON that blends the lists.

Comment: @AminUddin, you really have 2 options. 1) if you insist on using ng-grid, create a json object that reflects your data and relationships. 2) The better way is not to use ng-grid at all. You should just use ng-repeat and custom directives. You're trying to build a house with a screw-driver.

Comment: @AminUddin, I worked hard to give you an accurate answer and what I feel is a reasonable alternative. Do you disagree with my answer or simply not like the result?

Comment: Thanks your co-operation. I am trying to avoid ng-grid. Because most of the of my developing software object are complex. In web I could not find any js grid which support such type of features.Your comments is right (You're trying to build a house with a screw-driver. )

Comment: @ Dave A, You have already gain 25. You were directly answer by subgrid which was not correct. And your answer does not solve my problem. I knew that nested grid does not supported in ng-grid. But I posted such problem in stackoverflow in order to aware ng-grid author or contributors. Else I wanted to get ans. from community if some one solved it already(in another way).

Answer (score 0):

It's just hack the example for each row have same sub rowcount.

```
<body ng-controller="facultycontroller">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
</body>
```

```
var faculty = angular.module('faculty', ['ngGrid']);

faculty.controller('facultycontroller', function facultycontroller($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.facdata = [{
    examname: 'test' 
  },{
    examname: 'test2'
  }];

  $scope.rowHeight = 30;

  $scope.updateGrid = function() {
      $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'facdata',
      rowHeight: $scope.fac1data.length * $scope.rowHeight,
      columnDefs: [
        {field: 'examname',displayName: 'Exam Name'},
        {field: '', displayName: 'Subjects' , cellTemplate: '<div  ng-grid="gridOptions1"  ></div>'
      }]
    };
  }

  $scope.fac1data = [{
    abc: 'value',
    def: 'value2'
  }, {
    abc: 'value3',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value1',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value2',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value23',
    def: 'value14'
  }, {
    abc: 'value433',
    def: 'value5554'
  }, {
    abc: 'value3555',
    def: 'value4878'
  }
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
   headerRowHeight: 0,
    data: 'fac1data',
    rowHeight: $scope.rowHeight,
    columnDefs: [
      {  field: 'abc',    displayName: 'abc'    },
      { field: 'def',      displayName: 'def'   }]
  }

  $scope.updateGrid();

  $scope.fac1data = [{
    abc: 'value2',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value34',
    def: 'value4'
  }, {
    abc: 'value23',
    def: 'value14'
  }, {
    abc: 'value433',
    def: 'value5554'
  }, {
    abc: 'value3555',
    def: 'value4878'
  }
  ];

  $scope.updateGrid();

});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wSd880e7cm2BlOkfdrAW?p=preview)

Edit :
If main row have different sub row count, it not work. I only have idea. Must be fork ui-grid, and redesign it to auto height. The official ui-grid is design fixed height at gridTemplate.html and use absolute top position.

Comment: Please don't include mysterious shortened URLs. They're scary.

Comment: I post plunker or fiddle link, it can't be send, I try use 'code' button, it's not work.

Comment: Code is indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: I get it, I can't just post a plunker or fiddle link, it need some code. Thank for your help.

Comment: Then post some code? I edited your question and copy-pasted the code from your Plunker.

Comment: Yes, I don't know must be 'some code' in post. If i only have link, it can't be send.

Comment: It's forced. The idea is embeded data and re-sizing. You've provided an example that works for very limited situations. It requires that data neatly fit within a fixed space. What if theres 1 row or 200?

Comment: Thanks, The above answer is correct for fixed length. But my object structure like this...

Comment: Thanks, The above answer is correct for fixed length. But my object structure like this...  public class Order
 {
   public string OrderNO(get; set;)
   public DateTime OrderDate(get; set;)
   public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetailList {get; set;}
 }
 public class OrderDetail 
 {
   public string ProductName{get; set;}
   public decimal Price{get;set;}
   public int Quantity{get;set;}
 } In this case I do not get same detail record length all time.

Comment: Yes. If main row have different sub row count, it not work. I only have idea. Must be fork ui-grid, and redesign it to auto height. The official ui-grid is design fixed height at gridTemplate.html and use absolute top position.