# Splitting a grid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid with 3 columns and multiple rows (loaded from json) that I have created using the ng-grid plugin. I want to be able to split the table - Say, when I click on row 5, another table should be inserted (with an indent) in-between rows 5 and 6. I am not even sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about nested table in ng-grid

You can find answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205911/why-nested-ng-grid-height-does-not-work)

Also there is plunker demo

plnkr.co/edit/NAHRHGhCjjS543Vfo5pg plukker